# Will this AM radio receiver work?

Tags: radio, analysis, receiver

What I'm essentially trying to do is to add an amplifier to a simple passive radio receiver:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVaMXe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

XFMR2 consists of two inductors 0.4 uH and 730 uH. C3 varies between 35 and 235 pF (or something like this). Numbers and the whole left part is taken from [here](http://www2.eng.cam.ac.uk/~dmh/ptialcd/trf/trf.htm).

The idea is to demodulate negative part of a signal via D1, R1, C5 and pass it to an inverting amplifier based on OA1.

If this circuit is going to work: I'm interested in receiving medium frequencies. It is said they're quite tough to receive in a city due to industrial and home EM noise, especially during days. Am I going to need something more sophisticated instead of this circuit? (not going into antenna discussion here)

Also, why germanium diode OA47? Can I replace it with a Schottky diode?

Comment: You're running the OP07C at half the minimum recommended supply voltage. It has absolutely no headroom left. It's designed for ±15 volts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It wont work .C4 stops the detector diode from working .Remove C4 by shorting it .R2 is way way to low and will load the tuned circuit meaning no selectivity.Use a high impedence buffer like say a MPF102 or an opamp to keep some selectivity.Your audio output stage looks iffy so recheck the biasing .The Ge diode is slightly better than the Schotty here.

Comment: I would move C4 to before the opamp and add a bit of bias after it to get near the middle of your OP drive range.  Selecting a low voltage (many modern devices) amp is critical and everything @Autistic said.